# Help understanding 'require', want to import code from lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something in my /lib folder like:

```
/lib/some_folder/some_file.rb
/lib/some_folder2/some_file2.rb
```

Now in my rails 3 app, I will reference methods from both some_file and some_file2

How can I reference them w/o having to fully qualify them based on their module::class_name.method ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use the `Include` statement as shown in the following example:

**module_test.rb:**

```
module ModuleTest
  class Class1
    def do_something
      puts "Class 1 do something"
    end
  end
end
```

**module_test2.rb:**

```
module ModuleTest2
  class Class2
    def do_something
      puts "Class 2 do something"
    end
  end
end
```

**Qualifying the module:**

```
require_relative 'module_test'
require_relative 'module_test2'

ModuleTest::Class1.new.do_something
ModuleTest2::Class2.new.do_something
```

<sub>**Outputs:**</sub>

```
'Class 1 do something'
'Class 2 do something'
```

**Using the include statment:**

```
require_relative 'module_test'
require_relative 'module_test2'
include ModuleTest
include ModuleTest2

Class1.new.do_something
Class2.new.do_something
```

<sub>**Outputs:**</sub>

```
'Class 1 do something'
'Class 2 do something'
```